# SQL: Check if now Timestamp is greater than expired Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I want to Check if the Timestamp of now is greater than my Expired Timestamp:

```
id  |  created_timestamp  |   expired_timestamp
1   |     1542570971      |   1542743771
```

I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM premium WHERE expired_timestamp >= now();
```

Nothing works :/

Answer (score 4):

You simply need to use [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function:

```
SELECT * FROM premium 
WHERE expired_timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP();
```

[`NOW()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function returns current datetime in `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` format. While `Unix_Timestamp()` function will return the current datetime's unix timestamp value (unsigned integer). You need to use the latter in your case.

Comment: You are my Herooo.. Thank YOUUU <3

Comment: @ElyasNice happy to help :) Although Gordon was 1 second faster than me !

Answer (score 2):

I think you want [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp):

```
SELECT *
FROM premium
WHERE expired_timestamp >= UNIX_TIMETAMP();
```